# Using query result field as database name in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Probably a long shot with this...

I have two databases "Job Register" and "Job001".

I want to retrieve a list of the jobs that have had a meeting, and the last time the meeting took place (which is determined by the latest revision of a certain document).

The list of jobs that have had a meeting is easy enough as they are in the same database and have a specific column for this information. The tricky bit is then to have an additional column retrieved that uses the retrieved job number to JOIN that job's database and check a document number "DOC001" in this case for it's latest revision and retrieve the "date_modified".

Please see the attached image of the two databases and the desired query result.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me how we can even join these two tables together.  You might want to explain that better.

Comment: Database <> Table. Those are tables, not databases. Tables are just one type of object that a database can contain.

Comment: I guess by JobNumber, but why in the first table the datatype is varchar and for the second is INT?

Comment: So, you have a `Job002` and `Job003`, etc table? If so, this screams bad design. The better solution here is to fix your design. Is this something that you are able to do?

Comment: Also, why is the value for `date_modified` in your Query results `05/11/2018`? The latest date in your `Job001` table is `10/11/2018`; should the value not therefore be that?

Comment: All, thank you for your responses. Larnu - This was a quick example they actually are different databases, I missed the table names off "Job Register" Table = "Jobs", "Job001" Table = "Documents". Sami - Again this was a quick example mockup, the "job_number" column in database "Job001" was meant to be "job_number_id" as a foreign key. Larnu - I do have "Job002" and "Job003" and I know this is a bad design, until the new system development is finished I am stuck trying to bodge onto what we currently have. Also we only had SQL Server Express and I was worried of Database size limit.

Comment: Larnu - The latest date is 10/11/2018 but this is for a document I'm not interested in in my query. Thanks again all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear a bit, but I think you are looking for

```
SELECT JR.JobNumber,
       JR.IsComplete,
       J.DateModified
FROM JobRegister JR INNER JOIN Job001 J
ON JR.JobNumber = J.JobNumber
WHERE DocumentRevision = 'B';
```

Also `JobNumber` in both tables should be the same datatype.

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa6e66e560ed367b879f3a403f38abb8)**

Comment: Sami, thank you very much for taking the time to do this. This is exactly what I want, but where you have "INNER JOIN Job001 J" I need this to be dynamic based on the value retrieved in "JR.JobNumber". This probably isn't even possible, but I thought I'd ask. so something like:

Comment: Please see response as an answer.

Comment: @squatman That's a very bad idea, you will need to use DynamicSQL

Comment: Ok Sami, thanks for your help. I guess for the time being I will have to get the result with some programming in the application. Thanks.

Comment: @squatman How would you know which Job table to join with? Job001? Job002?...etc

Comment: There would be a "WHERE IsComplete = True" then for all the job numbers retrieved it would have to join each of those databases for each row to get the latest date for each.

Comment: @squatman The best way is to fix your design, this is not a good thing to do.

Comment: Ok, appreciate that Sami. Thanks for your time and responses.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT JR.JobNumber,
       JR.IsComplete,
       J.DateModified
FROM JobRegister JR INNER JOIN CONCAT('Job', JR.JobNumber) J
ON JR.JobNumber = J.JobNumber
WHERE DocumentRevision = 'B';
```